# Which methods can be used to make thread wait for an event and then continue its execution?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events, event-handling

I have a thread running that delegates out some tasks. When a single task is complete, an event is raised saying that it has completed. These tasks need to be run in a specific order and need to wait for the previous task to finish. How can I make the thread wait until it receives the "task completed" event? (Aside from the obvious eventhandler that sets a flag and then a while loop polling the flag)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I often use the [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) wait handle when I need to wait for an asynchronous task to finish:

```
public void PerformAsyncTasks()
{
    SomeClass someObj = new SomeClass()
    AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false); 
    // create and attach event handler for the "Completed" event
    EventHandler eventHandler = delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        waitHandle.Set();  // signal that the finished event was raised
    } 
    someObj.TaskCompleted += eventHandler;

    // call the async method
    someObj.PerformFirstTaskAsync();    
    // Wait until the event handler is invoked
    waitHandle.WaitOne();
    // the completed event has been raised, go on with the next one
    someObj.PerformSecondTaskAsync();
    waitHandle.WaitOne();
    // ...and so on
}
```

Comment: Based off the first answer, I am doing something very similar to this. What is the difference between AutoResetEvent and EventWaitHandle initialized with EventResetMode.AutoReset?

Comment: @MGSoto: I think the difference is minimal (if any): `AutoResetEvent` inherits from `EventWaitHandle`, and seems to use the constructor of its base class to pass `EventResetMode.AutoReset` to it.

Comment: Don't forget, that AutoResetEvent, WaitHandles etc implements IDisposable

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to use an [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx) to signal completion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) for this.

The thread that needs to process first just takes the resetEvent, and waits until the end to Set the event.

The thread that needs to wait can hold a handle to it, and call resetEvent.WaitOne().  This will block that thread until the first completes.

This allows you to handle blocking and ordering of events in a very clean manner.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good results by using a callback method that the worker thread calls when its done. It beats polling and makes it easy to pass parameters back to the caller.